# Removing td.actions from cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove `td.actions` from a WooCommerce cart page via PHP. The table contains a `Coupon` field, and a `Update Basket` button.  I searched around, but only found ways to hide using CSS. Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: more informaiton requried. need sample code

Comment: .woocommerce table.cart td.actions, .woocommerce-page #content table.cart td.actions, .woocommerce-page table.cart td.actions {
    display: none;
}

Comment: have you tried using js?

Comment: The above is the CSS that hides the table. I can't find the PHP though.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with JS.